# using const double* const as a template parameter - code perfomance question

Tags: c++, templates, double, constexpr, precompiled

I'm trying to understand the under the hood of using `const double* const` as template. I have some very basic calculation I want to perform efficiently and I don't know how the c++ compiler works(what is the assembly code).

The idea is to create a template for a function that get 3 constant doubles as template parameters and a double as an argument.

```cpp
constexpr double p1 = 1;
constexpr double p2 = 2;
constexpr double p3 = 3;

template <const double* const a, 
        const double* const b, 
        const double* const c>
inline double func(double value)
{
    constexpr double d = *a - *b;
    constexpr double e = *a - *c;
    constexpr double ratio = d / e;
    constexpr double remain = *c - *a * ratio;

    return value * ratio + remain;
}

double func2(double c)
{
    return func<&p1,&p2,&p3>(c);
}
```

My question is if for every p1,p2,p3 the `func< p1,p2,p3 >(c)` will be compiled to `c * < const value > + < const value >`

or the compiler can't extract the const values in compilation time and the full function will execute in run time.

Comment: There's no way to answer this question except by looking at the generated code. The C++ standard does not tell compilers how they must compile their code.

Comment: Your code isn't valid, you try to convert `const double` to `const double *` here `func<p1,p2,p3>`.

Comment: FWIW on my compiler `func` was reduced to a multiplication by a constant (and `func2` was inlined as well) but YMMV.

Comment: I edited the code to what the OP clearly intended.

Comment: For `func<&p1,&p2,&p3>(c)` the compiler would be allowed to optimize the code to `c * 0.5 + 2.5`. As these addresses won't refer to mutable data or addresses.

Comment: For your convenience, here is what the three largest compilers do with your code: https://godbolt.org/z/EeoO8v

Comment: Thanks, when I changed my code(of course I don't use names like func, func2, a, b...) I removed the &'s.

Answer (score 8):

[When looking at the compiled output](https://godbolt.org/z/N6BXtm) you can see that the compiler reduces `func2` to a multiplication and an addition with two constants. It doesn’t even call `func` any more.

However, the compiler is perfectly capable of producing *the same* code without the need to muck around with non-type template arguments:

```cpp
inline double func(
    double const a,
    double const b,
    double const c,
    double const value
) {
    double const d = a - b;
    double const e = a - c;
    double const ratio = d / e;
    double const remain = c - a * ratio;

    return value * ratio + remain;
}
```

This produces the exact same output.

Answer (score 6):

The standard doesn't say.  It doesn't even say that the code must be compiled - it could be interpreted.

In practise, every current C++ *does* compile (although some compile to a bytecode which is then JITed).  Furthermore, every compiler I know about will avoid doing a division at runtime *in optimized builds*.  (In non-optimized builds, all bets are off).

The only way to be sure is to look at the generated assembly - Godbolt.org is very good for this.

Answer (score 0):

In general, C++ doesn't require evaluation of floating-point expressions at compile time. That's because floating-point typically has knobs that you can tweak at runtime, such as changing the rounding mode, so anything evaluated at compile-time could easily run afoul of runtime changes to the behavior of floating-point arithmetic.

That's reflected in the requirement that non-type template arguments can't be floating-point values. So, [for example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), with `template <auto n> struct B { };`, `B<2.5>` is an error.

In this question, the template is being instantiated with a pointer. That's okay; the fact that the pointer points at a `double` does not invalidate it. Nonetheless, as you've seen, the compiler won't calculate the result at compile-time. So all those `constexpr` markers aren't doing anything; the results are all evaluated at runtime.